# Aes Encrypt and Decrypt null adds bytes

Tags: c#, node.js, encryption, encoding, cryptography

Hi there i'm using this encryption method to encrypt my json value in .net side

```
public static string Encrypt256(string text)
    {
        AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        aes.BlockSize = 128;
        aes.KeySize = 256;
        aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AesIV256);
        aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AesKey256);
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        byte[] src = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

        using (ICryptoTransform encrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor())
        {
            byte[] dest = encrypt.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length);
            Debug.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(dest));
            return Convert.ToBase64String(dest);
        }
    }
```

And im trying to decrypt it in Node Js side

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
  algorithm = process.env.tombalaCryptoAlgorithm,
  password = process.env.tombalaHmacPass,
  iv = '!QAZ2WSX#EDC4RFV'
function encrypt(text) {
  var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, password, iv)
  var encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'base64')
  encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
  return encrypted;
```

Comment: You should not post code as images. Please [edit] your question to include the node.js code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting your text to be encrypted to `Unicode` which means `UTF-16`.
In UTF-16 every character consists of two bytes. If the second byte is not used it is null as you have observed.

I assume you want `UTF-8` encoding. Therefore replace the line

```
byte[] src = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);
```

with

```
byte[] src = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
```